# Looking for more Webpack production bundle optimisation

Tags: javascript, webpack

I'm trying to reduce the output size of my application's JS bundle and looking around these are the plugins that I got so far to help me on this task:

```
config.plugins = [
 new webpack.DefinePlugin({
      'process.env': {
        'NODE_ENV': JSON.stringify('production')
      }
    }),
  new webpack.ContextReplacementPlugin(/moment[\/\\]locale$/, /en-gb/),
  new ExtractTextPlugin({ filename: "bundle.css" }),
  new webpack.LoaderOptionsPlugin({
    minimize: true,
    debug: false
  }),
  new webpack.optimize.UglifyJsPlugin({
    compress: {
      warnings: false,
      pure_getters: true,
      unsafe: true,
      unsafe_comps: true,
      screw_ie8: true,
    },
    output: {
      comments: false,
      screw_ie8: true,
    },
    mangle: {
      screw_ie8: true,
    },
    sourceMap: false,
    minimize: true
  }),
  new LodashModuleReplacementPlugin({ 'collections': true }),
  new DuplicatePackageCheckerPlugin()
];
```

I also set `devtool` to undefined for production.

And this is my `.babelrc` where I'm also doing some optimisations:

```
{
  "presets": [
    ["es2015", { "es2015": { "loose": true, "modules": false}}],
    "react",
    "stage-0",
  ],  
  "env": {
    "development": {
      "presets": ["react"]
    },
    "production": {
      "plugins": [
        ["transform-react-remove-prop-types", {
          "mode": "wrap",
        }]
      ]
    }
  },
  "plugins": ["lodash"]
}
```

Is there any other thing I can do? The bundle has been reduced a lot but still quite big.

Comment: look into code splitting

Comment: Wouldn't that be the same but split in more chunks?

Comment: https://medium.com/@nimgrg/analysing-and-minimising-the-size-of-client-side-bundle-with-webpack-and-source-map-explorer-41096559beca

Comment: gonna look that in detail @TravMatth. Thanks

Comment: yes, the point is to have users download only chunks they need and cache the rest